# Double sigma formula

Tags: summation, notation

i was looking through the page and didnt find a topic or a formula that explain what this means:

[image]

especially the red part. So can anyone help me and translate it to understand for dummy?

Link to formula: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/47076299220991AN_900.pdf

Something similar: [Interpreting formulas with $\Sigma \Sigma$ (two sigma)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153814/two-sigma-notation)

Comment: please consider converting the image to text. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Probably (*accel* $-$ *avg*) is something with two indices, and you are adding them all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is that a pedometer is supposed to estimate the distance
that a person walks, but acceleration is the only thing the sensor inside it can measure directly.
It is therefore necessary to convert acceleration to distance.

Given acceleration $a(t)$ as a function of time and a starting velocity,
we can determine velocity $v(t)$ as a function of time via the integration

$$ v(t) = v(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t a(\tau)\, d\tau.$$

Given velocity $v(t)$ as a function of time and a starting position,
we can determine position $x(t)$ as a function of time via the integration

$$ x(t) = x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t v(\tau)\, d\tau.$$

A hip-mounted pedometer measures mainly up-and-down acceleration 
in order to estimate the difference in height of the hip from its highest 
point to its lowest point. If we start at the highest (or lowest) point, 
calling this time $t_0$, then $v(t_0) = 0$. 
We can also set $x(t_0) = 0$, that is, we will measure height relative
to the starting point. Then

$$ x(t) = \int_{t_0}^t v(\tau)\, d\tau 
= \int_{t_0}^t \int_{t_0}^\tau a(u)\,du\,d\tau.$$

That is, distance is a double integral of acceleration.

But the accelerometer cannot actually know the exact acceleration
at all times and integrate it analytically; all it has is a sequence
of measurements taken at regular intervals. It can use those measurements
to make a Riemannian sum that will approximate the integral of acceleration
estimate velocity at each interval, and make a Riemannian sum of those
estimates in order to estimate height at each interval.
That is, the double integral becomes a sum of sums, which is what 
the $\sum\sum$ notation is meant to signify.
It is assumed that when faced with an actual sequence of measurements
taken by the accelerometer, you will be able to assign index numbers
to those measurements and use those numbers as the indices of the two sums.
So if you have $n$ measurements numbered $1, 2, \ldots, n$
from the top to the bottom of a stride, the change in height is
approximated by

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^j a(t_i). $$

---

Note that the graphs of the "acceleration" values measured by the pedometer
show all positive values. But we know the actual average acceleration over
a stride (or half stride) is zero. Apparently, the numbers we get
for "acceleration" represent the actual acceleration plus some constant bias,
and the bias is the average value of the measurements.
Presumably that is why the formula in the  paper is written

$$ \sum \sum (accel - avg)$$

instead of $ \sum \sum a(t_i). $

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you would at least tell us what **page** that was on so we could check exactly what it said!

First, there must be some *indices* associated with each sum- something like $\sum_{m= 1}^M \sum_{n= 1}^N$- and the quantity inside must depend on n and m.  That means "do the summation over all values of n so that you have a result that depends only on the index m. The sum those for all value of m.

For example, $\sum_{m= 1}^3 \sum_{n= 1}^2 2m- n^2$.  Then $\sum_{n=1}^2 2m- n^2= (2m- 1)+ (2m- 4)= 4m- 5$ so the second sum becomes $\sum_{m= 1}^3 4m- 5= (4- 5)+ (8- 5)+ (12- 5)= -1+ 3+ 7= 9$.

$\sum_{m= 1}^3 \sum_{n= 1}^2 2m- n^2= 9$