# Two-sigma notation k-means clustering

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, summation, notation

I have referred to this question: [Interpreting formulas with $\Sigma \Sigma$ (two sigma)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153814/two-sigma-notation), to get an understanding of how two-sigma notation works. But this is insufficient for my purposes.

I am looking at a k-means clustering algorithm, where the problem is the following:

$$\displaystyle{\text{argmin}_{C_1,..C_k;\pmb{c_1},..\pmb{c_k}}\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{x \in C_i} ||\pmb{x}-\pmb{c_i}||^2}$$

where $\pmb{x}$ is a data vector, e.g. $\pmb{x_1}=(1,2,3)'$, $\pmb{c_i}$ is the centroid of $C_i$ cluster. I conceptually understand what the above means, namely we find such centroids for each cluster that minimize the total squared distance between each centroid in a cluster and datapoints in that cluster. But I fail to understand how I would expand out the above expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the double sigma notation is that its a sum of sums:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\sum\limits_{x \in C_i} \|x - c_i\|^2 = \sum\limits_{x \in C_1} \|x - c_1\|^2  + \ldots + \sum\limits_{x \in C_k} \|x - c_k\|^2$$

Each inner sum iterates over the data points of the according (current) Cluster $C_i$.

Comment: That makes sense. Welcome to stack exchange :) It will be my honour to accept your very first answer here :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm happy to help :).